# Fetch one out of two Numbers out of String

Tags: regex

I hav a list of strings, such as: `Ø20X400`
I need to extract the first of the numbers - between Ø and X

I've come so far to match the numbers in general with `\d+` - as simple as it is...
But I need an expression to get the first value separated, not both of them...

Comment: How does `\n+` match numbers?

Comment: `\n` means 'newline', you want to use `\d` which means 'digit'.

Comment: Ah, my bad, typed wrong :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds `(?<=..)` and `(?=..)`:

```
(?<=Ø)\d+(?=X)
```

or in Java style:

```
(?<=Ø)\\d+(?=X)
```

A second way is to use a capture group:

```
Ø(\d+)X
```

or

```
Ø(\\d+)X
```

Then you can extract the content of the group.

Comment: I thought I knew *everything* about regular expressions until I saw this "lookaround" concept. Cool!

Comment: @JimL.: lookaround is a shortcut for lookbehind and lookahead. See www.regular-expressions.info for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

The regex engines I know parse `\n` as a newline. `\d` is used for numbers.

The following regex gives you the first number between a `Ø` and a `X` in a capture group:

```
^.*?Ø(\d+)X.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/7jTf1d38hkLmFTN0)

Comment: There's no point in the `^.*?` part in the beginning and the `.*` part at the end unless he want to capture the whole input as well.

Answer (score 0):

This Regex will do it for you, `(\d+?)X`, and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/D1bRg5sOVw). See, you want to group digits together, but make it non-greedy, ending the evaluation on `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\d+(?=\D)
```

Should find first number wich has some not a number ahead

Answer (score 0):

With normal regular expressions, I would say:

`Ø(\d+)X`

This finds the `Ø` character, followed by one or more numbers, followed by an X.  Also, the numbers will be stored in the first capture group.  Capture groups differ from one regex implementation to another, but this would typically be denoted by `\1`.  Capture group zero, `\0`, is usually the matched string itself.  In this version, `\d` denotes digits 0-9, but if your regex engine uses `\n` for that purpose, use:

`Ø(\n+)X`